# JQuery will not recognize a created element

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble getting jquery to recognize an element that is created from a form change.  I have it set up so when i select something a link is created with but when I add a click function to the created item nothing will happen.  How can i make this work?

```
$(function() {

var i = $('#nav li').size() + 1;

$('a#add').click(function() {
    $('<li>' + i + '<a href="#" id="add">yes</a></li>').appendTo('ul');
    i++;
});

$('a#remove').click(function() {
    $('li:last').remove();
    i--;
});


});
```

html code

```
<ul id="nav">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" id="add">Add List Item</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="remove">Remove LI</a>
```

Comment: Why are you adding another `a#add` to the ul?

Comment: I don't see you adding any handlers to the li you're adding to your list. Did you omit that part of your code?

Comment: `id` should always be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use live to bind event handlers for dynamically created elements.
Your current code will create multiple html elements with same id which is not valid.
You can use class names instead to identify the src elements.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var i = $('#nav li').size() + 1;
    $('a.add').live("click", function() {
        $('<li>' + i + '<a href="#" class="add">yes</a></li>').appendTo('ul');
        i++;
    });

    $('a.remove').live("click", function() {
        $('li:last').remove();
        i--;
    });
});
```

html code

```
<ul id="nav">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="add">Add List Item</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="remove">Remove LI</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jquery to this:

```
$(function() {
    var i = $('#nav li').size() + 1;

    $('a#add').live('click', function() {
        $('<li>' + i + '<a href="#" id="add">yes</a></li>').appendTo('ul');
        i++;
    });

    $('a#remove').live('click', function() {
        $('li:last').remove();
        i--;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the .click here.  .click is just .bind with the mouse event action.  You have to use the [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

To attach an event to a selector and all other created by jQuery, you must use the .live() function instead of the .click() shorthand.

You code to attach the 'click' event to you 'a#add' link would look like this :

```
$('a#add').live('click', function() {
    $('<li>' + i + '<a href="#" id="add">yes</a></li>').appendTo('ul');
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`id="add"` is only allowed on one element per page.  If you use it more than once, bizarre things can happen.  Change your code to:

```
$(function() {
    var i = $('#nav li').size() + 1;

    $('a#add').click(function() {
        $('<li>' + i + '<a href="#" class="add">yes</a></li>').appendTo('ul');
        i++;
    });

    $('ul a.add').live('click', function() {
        // handle any link with class "add" that was dynamically added to the ul
    });

    $('a#remove').live('click', function() {
        $('li:last').remove();
        i--;
    });
});
```